# List inside list with checkbox in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to create a checkbox with select all functionality , here is my sample json

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "categories 1",
    "child": [
      {
        "id": 29,
        "name": "sub 1"
       
        
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "sub 2"
       
        
      },
      {
        "id": 31,
        "name": "sub 3 "
       
        
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "categories 2",
    "child": [
      {
        "id": 23,
        "name": "sub 1"
       
        
      },
      {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "sub 1"
       
        
      },
      {
        "id": 25,
        "name": "sub 1"
       
        
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "categories 3",
    "child": [
      {
        "id": 222,
        "name": "sub 1"
       
        
      },
      {
        "id": 229,
        "name": "sub 1"
       
        
      },
      {
        "id": 229,
        "name": "sub 1"
       
        
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How i need is

[image]

If I check categories 1 all under categories should be selected/unselected and if I select category 2 all under that should be selected and also individual item also need to be selected

Select all should select all checkbox in all categories

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 50,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Wrap(
                       children: [
                          Container(
                             child: Icon(
                                Icons.check_box,
                             )
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: Text(
                              'Category ${index+1}'
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 3,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index2) {
                          return Wrap(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.check_box,
                                )
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Text(
                                'Subcategory ${index2+1}'
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        }
                      )
                    )
                    
                  ]
                )
              );
            }
          )
       )
```

Then you have to put your own logic according to your requirement.

Comment: Check box not considered ?

Comment: This is how you have to manage listview inside listview. The other logics you need to set according to your need.

Comment: i have edited my code a little. check it.

Answer (score 0):

I think using this is more flexible, [tree_view](https://pub.dev/packages/tree_view):

```
var treeView = TreeView(
  parentList: [
    Parent(
      parent: Text('Desktop'),
      childList: ChildList(
        children: <Widget>[
          Parent(
            parent: Text('documents'),
            childList: ChildList(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Resume.docx'),
                Text('Billing-Info.docx'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Text('MeetingReport.xls'),
          Text('MeetingReport.pdf'),
          Text('Demo.zip'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: He's not asking about the view. More to about how to handling checkboxes inside nested Listview.